# ARM Keil error #17 expected a "]", C3910W: Old syntax

Tags: c, compiler-errors, arm, microcontroller, keil

Hi I am trying to build a program on Keil μVision v.5.12.

The errors seems to be only "one" (expecting a `]`) . But the code works (compiles and runs without err/warnings) **on** my linux partition.

```
Rebuild target 'Target 1'
compiling ax.c...
ax.c: Warning: C3910W: Old syntax, please use '--c99'.
23_2\fixvector3d.h(30): warning:  #1-D: last line of file ends without a newline
  #endif
23_2\fixquat.h(73): warning:  #1-D: last line of file ends without a newline
  #endif
23_2\fixstring.h(21): warning:  #1-D: last line of file ends without a newline
  #endif
23_2\ax.c(46): error:  #17: expected a "]"
        mf16 Adew =  {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(47): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                     {[0 ... DIM-    1] = fix16_from_int(0)},            
23_2\ax.c(48): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                     {[0 ... DIM-    1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
23_2\ax.c(58): error:  #17: expected a "]"
        mf16 sqrtD = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(59): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                     {[0 ... DIM-    1] = fix16_from_int(0)},            
23_2\ax.c(60): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                     {[0 ... DIM-    1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
23_2\ax.c(64): error:  #17: expected a "]"
        mf16 transE = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(65): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                       {[0 ... DIM-    1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(66): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                       {[0 ... DIM-    1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
23_2\ax.c(70): error:  #17: expected a "]"
        mf16 inv_eigenvectors = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(71): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                         {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(72): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                        {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
23_2\ax.c(76): error:  #17: expected a "]"
        mf16 eigenvectors = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(77): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                     {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(78): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                       {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
23_2\ax.c(82): error:  #17: expected a "]"
        mf16 whiteningMatrix = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(83): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                       {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(84): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                   {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
23_2\ax.c(88): error:  #17: expected a "]"
        mf16 dewhiteningMatrix = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(89): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                       {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(90): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                      {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
23_2\ax.c(94): error:  #17: expected a "]"
        mf16 Bold = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(95): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                      {[0 ... DIM-    1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(96): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                       {[0 ... DIM-    1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
23_2\ax.c(100): error:  #17: expected a "]"
        mf16 tempMatrixOne = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(101): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                           {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(102): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                   {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
23_2\ax.c(106): error:  #17: expected a "]"
        mf16 tempMatrixTwo = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(107): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                         {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
23_2\ax.c(108): error:  #17: expected a "]"
                   {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
assembling startup_ARMCM0.s...
compiling system_ARMCM0.c...
system_ARMCM0.c: Warning: C3910W: Old syntax, please use '--c99'.
".\Objects\ax.axf" - 30 Error(s), 5 Warning(s).
```

** The part of my code where the errors appear to be

```
mf16 Adew =  {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                            {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},        
                            {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_Adew;     
ptr_Adew = &Adew;

mf16 identity = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{fix16_from_int(1),fix16_from_int(0),fix16_from_int(0)},
                               {fix16_from_int(0),fix16_from_int(1),fix16_from_int(0)},
                               {fix16_from_int(0),fix16_from_int(0),fix16_from_int(1)}}};
mf16 *ptr_identity;     
ptr_identity = &identity;

mf16 sqrtD = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                            {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},        
                            {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_sqrtD;        
ptr_sqrtD = &sqrtD;

mf16 transE = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                            {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                            {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_transE;
ptr_transE = &transE;

mf16 inv_eigenvectors = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                       {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                       {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_inv_eigenvectors;         
ptr_inv_eigenvectors = &inv_eigenvectors;   

mf16 eigenvectors = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                   {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                   {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_eigenvectors;                             
ptr_eigenvectors = &eigenvectors;                           

mf16 whiteningMatrix = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                      {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                      {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_whiteningMatrix;
ptr_whiteningMatrix = &whiteningMatrix;

mf16 dewhiteningMatrix = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                        {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                        {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_dewhiteningMatrix;
ptr_dewhiteningMatrix = &dewhiteningMatrix;

mf16 Bold = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                            {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                            {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_Bold;
ptr_Bold = &Bold;

mf16 tempMatrixOne = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                    {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                    {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_tempMatrixOne;
ptr_tempMatrixOne = &tempMatrixOne;

mf16 tempMatrixTwo = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                    {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                    {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_tempMatrixTwo;
ptr_tempMatrixTwo = &tempMatrixTwo;

mf16 Btranspose = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                                {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_Btranspose;
ptr_Btranspose = &Btranspose;

mf16 Bnew = {DIM, DIM, 0, {{[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                            {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)},
                            {[0 ... DIM-1] = fix16_from_int(0)}}};
mf16 *ptr_Bnew;
ptr_Bnew = &Bnew;
```

[image]
What did i do wrong? (am i forgeting anything setting up my keil project?, perhaps a .h? or is the [0 ... dimension] declaring my matrices? )

Comment: Ranges like `[0 ... 9]` are a GCC extension, so may not be supported on other compilers.

Comment: @interjay yep! simple enough or may I say that I was lazy enough to try to change my code... thank you!! 
Now I have linking problems....
How do I point out your answer as...correct answer? Or should I answer my question?

Comment: Looks like ouah posted an answer, so you can accept his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [interjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189205/interjay) put it in the comments, you are using a C extension specific to `gcc` and not compatible on Keil.

From `gcc` [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html):

> To initialize a range of elements to the same value, write ‘[first ... last] = value’. This is a GNU extension. For example,
>
> ```
> int widths[] = { [0 ... 9] = 1, [10 ... 99] = 2, [100] = 3 };
> ```

Comment: Do you know how and if I can see exactly where in the compiling file is the error: ` Warning: C3910W: Old syntax, please use '--c99'. ` generated?

Comment: @Franx I fixed the link.

Comment: @Franx regarding the `--c99` warning, I can see in the code you pasted that you are mixing declarations and statements (assignment statements in your case): it is not allowed in c90 and only allowed since c99.